# Selenium for .net 3.5 visual studio

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

Can I run Selenium in Visual Studio 208? I tried to run, its giving error.

[image]

Comment: Did you look at all the errors? Your references are not right. You should use NuGet to install what you need instead of trying to set it up yourself.

Comment: @JeffC, Agreed. But I did not have Nuget in Visual Studio 2008. As you said, I was using wrong reference.(probably Selenium dll for .Net 4.5)

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question, since I got to know the reason of above error.

The above error is being shown because I am trying to refer Selenium dll for .net 4 or above.
Download Selenium from NuGet package manager and go to the downloaded path and "`packages`" folder.

```
Eg. ./packages/Selenium.WebDriver.3.141.0/lib
```

The below folders may be listed:

```
net35
net40
net45
netstandard2.0
```

Use appropriate Selenium webdriver dlls.(For Visual Studio 2008, use `net35`)